# Nginx always redirecting http to https

Tags: redirect, nginx, dns, digital-ocean, http-status-code-302

Hiyas, Im trying to redirect my non-www domain to a digitalocean droplet serving localhost:3000. When I type in my http://non-www domain, I get a 302 redirect to the https version of the non-www domain.

Here's the pastebin to my config stuff - http://pastebin.com/89HP07cW

I also added A record to digitalocean domain, to point to ip. And 2 cnames, * points to @, and www points to @. I'm just hacking now, reading through all the solutions and config file seems straight forward, but not working for me.

Comment: Why are you using ``proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';`` I this this may be redirecting from http to https.

Comment: I believe its for websockey proxying - http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html; Which I think meteor requires. I removed, still didn't help. I go from www.domain to domain on a 301, Then http://domain to https://domain on a 302. I am omiting my nginx default file in sites-enabled.

Comment: Do you get your app when you curl http://107.170.46.136:3000 from the instance? Assuming, the nginx is indeed using the block you have posted, the issue is somewhere upstream.

Comment: curl 104.131.178.125:3000 returns empty. curl -I gamengineers.co returns 302.